# How to install superagent (or any request library) into Serverless Framework AWS Lambda function?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, aws-lambda, serverless

I want my lambda function to be able to make network requests.

Here is my provider

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
```

I have `package.json` and `node_modules` at the root of the project.

I'm importing superagent like so: `const request = require('superagent')`.

But whenever I try to use it (`await request.post(url).send(body)`), it throws an error saying

```
ERROR   ERR TypeError: Cannot read property 'request' of undefined
    at Request.request
```

Comment: Check that your package.json contains the superagent dependency, and that it's not a devDependency. Then serverless should bundle it into lambda. Your can verify that the dependency exists in the lambda  (if your lambda source bundle is small enough) by going to the aws lambda functions page and checking the source code tree.

Comment: How are you adding this code in the lambda? Are you using the web console to add the code for the lambda or are you uploading the package.zip file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use any external library to make a http/https request.
Instead you can use nodejs http/https modules.
Here is a working example of https request as a promise inspired from the example in Nodejs docs (link below):

```
const https = require('https');

const requestPromise = (options, request_body= '') => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let response_data;
    const post_req = https.request(options, (res) => {
      res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        if (response_data) {
          response_data += chunk;
        } else {
          response_data = chunk;
        }
      });
      res.on('end', () => {
        resolve(response_data);
      });
    });
    // request error
    post_req.on('error', (err) => {
      reject(err);
    });

    // post data and end request
    post_req.write(JSON.stringify(request_body));
    post_req.end();
  });
}
```

Here is how you use it :

```
  const request_body = {
    "data": "your data"
  };

  const request_options = {
    host: host,
    path: path,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json' // your headers
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(request_body)
  };
  const response = await requestPromise(request_options , request_body );
```

For more information check Nodejs docs:
https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback

Comment: Wow thank you. That did it. Still disappointed that there's not a lot of documentation  around setting up a request library

Comment: note that the suggested solution executes `JSON.stringify` twice on `request_body`.